# TypeError: client.player.createQueue is not a function - How to fix this error in Discord.js bots? Discord.js/v.14

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots, syntax-error

I have a problem generating my music bot for discord, as it is displaying the following error when running the bot. (Discord.js/v.14)

Line(50): `const queue = await client.player.createQueue(interaction.guild)`

Code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders')
const { QueryType } = require('discord-player')

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('play')
    .setDescription('Plays a song.')
    .addSubcommand((subcommand) => {
      return subcommand
        .setName('search')
        .setDescription('Searches for a song.')
        .addStringOption((option) => {
          return option
            .setName('searchterms')
            .setDescription('Search keywords.')
            .setRequired(true)
        })
    })
    .addSubcommand((subcommand) => {
      return subcommand
        .setName('playlist')
        .setDescription('Plays playlist from Youtube.')
        .addStringOption((option) => {
          return option
            .setName('url')
            .setDescription('Playlist URL.')
            .setRequired(true)
        })
    })
    .addSubcommand((subcommand) => {
      return subcommand
        .setName('song')
        .setDescription('Plays song from Youtube.')
        .addStringOption((option) => {
          return option
            .setName('url')
            .setDescription('URL of the song.')
            .setRequired(true)
        })
    }),

  async execute({ client, interaction }) {
    if (!interaction.member.voice.channel) {
      await interaction.reply(
        'You must be in a voice channel to uso this command.',
      )
      return
    }

    const queue = await client.player.createQueue(interaction.guild)

    if (!queue.connection) await queue.connect(interaction.member.voice.channel)

    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()

    if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === 'song') {
      const url = interaction.options.getString('url')

      const result = await client.player.search(url, {
        requestedBy: interaction.user,
        searchEngine: QueryType.YOUTUBE_VIDEO,
      })

      if (result.tracks.length === 0) {
        await interaction.reply('No results found...')
        return
      }

      const song = result.tracks[0]
      await queue.addTrack(song)

      embed
        .setDescription(`Added **[${song.title}](${song.url})** to the queue.`)
        .setThumbnail(song.thumbnail)
        .setFooter({ text: `Duration: ${song.duration}` })
    } else if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === 'playlist') {
      const url = interaction.options.getString('url')

      const result = await client.player.search(url, {
        requestedBy: interaction.user,
        searchEngine: QueryType.YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST,
      })

      if (result.tracks.length === 0) {
        await interaction.reply('No playlist found...')
        return
      }

      const playlist = result.tracks[0]
      await queue.addTracks(playlist)

      embed
        .setDescription(
          `Added **[${playlist.title}](${playlist.url})** to the queue.`,
        )
        .setThumbnail(playlist.thumbnail)
        .setFooter({ text: `Duration: ${playlist.duration}` })
    } else if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === 'search') {
      const url = interaction.options.getString('searchterms')

      const result = await client.player.search(url, {
        requestedBy: interaction.user,
        searchEngine: QueryType.AUTO,
      })

      if (result.tracks.length === 0) {
        await interaction.reply('No results found...')
        return
      }

      const song = result.tracks[0]
      await queue.addTrack(song)

      embed
        .setDescription(`Added **[${song.title}](${song.url})** to the queue.`)
        .setThumbnail(song.thumbnail)
        .setFooter({ text: `Duration: ${song.duration}` })
    }

    if (!queue.playing) await queue.play()

    await interaction.reply({
      embeds: [embed],
    })
  },
}
```

Error: `TypeError: client.player.createQueue is not a function`

I've tried doing some research involving this issue, but haven't had any answers that help me.

I believe that there may also be a problem with getQueue(), but the first problem I encountered was this one.

I would like a solution to resolve this.

Comment: What is `client.player`?

Comment: My file `index.js` have this code:

```client.player = new Player(client, {
  ytdlOptions: {
    quality: 'highestaudio',
    highWaterMark: 1 << 25,
  },
})```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using the [discord-player](https://discord-player.js.org/) package based on your code contents.

Since discord-player v5 and above, some internal changes were made which means that you should use the `player.nodes.create()` function to create a new queue. It can be found [here in the documentation](https://discord-player.js.org/docs/discord-player?type=class&target=GuildNodeManager&scrollTo=fm-create). Likewise, some other functions have changed too based on the new GuildNodeManager.

In this case, it would be:

```
const queue = await client.player.nodes.create(interaction.guild)
```

However, since you have not specified the version, I cannot guarantee that this is the solution for you. If you could provide what version of the discord-player package you are using, I could edit the answer.